# Bulk Collect and FOR loop when all the values for insert DML is not available

Tags: plsql

I want to insert 150K records from a source table into a destination table. The problem is that i have to calculate some values for the destination table too.
How should i use the bulk collect and for statement for the INSERT DML.

Please find the elaborate explanation below.

```
Source Table
Account_id | Status1| Status2

Table 1
Account_id | column2| column3| column4|column6|column7

Table 2
Account_id | column2| column3| column6|column9|column10
```

NOw I have to fetch the values from table 1 for the account_ids matching the source table and insert into table 2 where i have to populate column9 and column 10 dynamically.

Comment: I would be useful to know how you need to "populate `column9` and `column10` dynamically". If you can express that calculation is SQL, then a direct insert would still be your best option.

Comment: column 9 is seq generated and column 10 is the value which i ll be calculating inside the procedure before i do this operation.

Comment: It's very difficult to help you if you tell us everything but the most important part of your task...

Comment: Sorry @Codo . I am not sure what more I have to  add. Can you shoot your questions, so that i will be able to provide more details

Comment: I'm of course interested in column10. All you have said so far is that you'll be calculating it inside a procedure. But is the procedure needed at all? Do you need one or more parameters as input? Do you need the entire row or even several rows as input? That's fundamental information to fully answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

BULK COLLECT requires a lot of memory and in practice is only feasible if you process your data in chunks, i.e. about 1000 rows at a time. Otherwise the memory consumption will be too much for most systems.

- The best option is usually to create a single INSERT .. SELECT statement that retrieves, calculates and inserts all data at once.
- If this is not possible or far too complex, the second best option in my opinion is a pipelined function written in PL/SQL.
- The third best and usually easiest option is a simple PL/SQL loop that select row by row, calculates the required data and inserts it row by row. Performance wise it's usually the worst. But it can be still more than sufficient.

For more precise answers, you need to specify the exact problem at hand. Your question is rather broad.

Comment: Please find the elaborate explanation below.

Source Table
Account_id | Status1| Status2

Table 1
Account_id | column2

Comment: Please find the elaborate explanation below.

Source Table
Account_id | Status1| Status2

Table 1
Account_id | column2| column3| column4|column6|column7

Table 2
Account_id | column2| column3| column6|column9|column10


NOw I have to fetch the values from table 1 for the account_ids matching the source table and insert into table 2 where i have to populate column9 and column 10 dynamically.